# Calling R CMD build in package fails check with R should not be used without a path

Tags: r

I have created a meta package (meta in the sense that it helps with package management, versioning etc) that as part of its functionality creates a `.tar.gz` archive of a package.
For this I use this code: `a <- system(sprintf("R CMD build %s", tarball), intern = TRUE)`.

When I execute the code interactively from my session either by executing the examples section of the roxygen documentation or by running the tests from the console it works, but when the meta package is checked using `devtools::check(document = FALSE)` the following error is thrown and neither the example code can be executed nor the tests pass...

```
  > tarball <- system.file("examplePackage", package = "myMetaPackage")
  > my_custom_function_in_myMetaPackage(pkg = tarball)
  Warning in system(sprintf("R CMD build %s", tmp_pkg_dir_new), intern = TRUE) :
    running command 'R CMD build /tmp/Rtmpz44MQC/working_dir/RtmpjkjC2T/examplePackage.v20221220' had status 1
  [1] "'R' should not be used without a path -- see par. 1.6 of the manual"
```

I want to avoid including `devtools` or `pkgbuild` as a dependency as I want to keep the meta package as light as possible.

I have checked `1.6` of the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Writing-portable-packages) but couldn't find anything related? Are there any additional arguments that I need to pass to `R CMD build` in order to make it run in the test/check environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is referring to this bullet point in the manual:

> Do not invoke R by plain R, Rscript or (on Windows) Rterm in your
> examples, tests, vignettes, makefiles or other scripts. As pointed out
> in several places earlier in this manual, use something like
>
> "$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript" "$(R_HOME)/bin$(R_ARCH_BIN)/Rterm"
>
> with appropriate quotes (as, although not recommended, R_HOME can
> contain spaces).

Comment: For whatever reason, I had to leave out the parenthesis (eg `"$R_HOME/bin/R"`) but otherwise it works like a charm!